# Moving and renaming files with same name

Tags: batch-processing, batch-rename

I hoping i'm not posting this in the wrong section. (forgive me if I am).

I imported some pictures from an iphone application to my hard drive.
The problem is that each picture sits in its own folder and all the files/pictures have the same name.

Folder1
 |_Picture.jpg

Folder2
 |_Picture.jpg

Folder3
 |_Picture.jpg

And there are 400 folders/pictures..

I want to move all the pictures to a single folder and rename them either by appending an incremental random integer or by using the containing folder's name (The picture in Folder1 is picture1 and so on... )

I have standard terminal knowledge but no scripting skills.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For such a problem you could use several renaming tools out there in the market. They only need basic knowledge of Regular Expressions for fancy renaming of files/folders in bulk. The one that I have used in the past a lot is:

http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php